# How to encode BSON Int64 as JSON String using Mongo Java client

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

When calling `org.bson.Document.toJson()` for a document containing an Int64 (Java long) value, it is encoded using Mongo's "$numberLong" encoding. For example this code:

```
    Document parse = Document.parse("{}");
    parse.put("version", 1L);
    String json = parse.toJson();
```

Produces this JSON:

```
    { "version" : { "$numberLong" : "1" } }
```

In order to make it more interopable I'd like to encode it as String instead, i.e. like this:

```
    { "version" : "1" }
```

I've read the [wiki on codecs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/) and [extended JSON](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/extended-json/) as well as most of the Javadoc but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to register a custom JSON serializer for longs. Even the default `org.bson.codecs.LongCodec` doesn't seem to be the one that introduces the `$numberLong` syntax.

Obviously a simple setting (e.g. an equvalent to Gson's `setLongSerializationPolicy(LongSerializationPolicy.STRING)`) would be ideal but any way to make this work would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you should register a custom serializer for longs in general since `{ "version" : "1" }` could be interpreted as the field `version` being a string field. Even  `{ "version" : 1 }` would have a problem since it would be interpreted as an integer field and if the value is too big things might break. So what you want is to tell the serializer/deserializer that `version` is a long and should be converted accordingly (probably to/from a string).

Comment: The example above is contrived. In the real world I'm loading BSON from MongoDB, turning it to JSON, publishing it onto a message bus and the consumer on the other end parses it using Gson into a POJO. And Gson chokes on `{ "$numberLong" : "1" }`.

Frankly I'd be just as happy with a decent way to register a custom deserializer for Gson to be able to parse this.

Answer (score 0):

For get strict JSON you can use [com.mongodb.util.JSON](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html)
and method *serialize()*

```
JSON.serialize(parse)
```

Or you can use some JSON libraries. For example [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String gsonString = gson.toJson(parse);
```

Comment: it is deprecated, is there a new alternative?

Comment: For the Gson option, I haven't tried this but I'm pretty sure `gson.toJson(parse)` wouldn't yield anything useful if `parse` is a `Document`.

My current solution _does_ use Gson but it involves using `Document.toJson()` and then adding a custom deserialiser to Gson that can handle the `$numberLong` format to parse it back into an object. This works but is ugly and enormously wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

use json.simple

JSONObject.toJSONString(parse)